# How can I unescape something escaped by CSS.escape()?

Tags: javascript, css, escaping

`CSS.escape('12345')` returns `\31 2345`, however there's no CSS.unescape() function.

How would I go about converting `\31 2345` back to `12345`, using Javascript?

Comment: Note on tag edits: Unicode is not involved/relevant in general, or in specific. The escaping of 1, in the basic ASCII set, is due to being a number starting an identifier. Any Unicode codepoint, outside the small reserved ASCII set and related rules, can appear without escaping. That aside, it’s a reasonable question/ask.